# Why this first query doesn't work but the second query works?

Tags: mysql, sql

| Project_id | Employee_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |

Write a sql query that reports all the projects that have the most employee

| Project_id |
| --- |
| 1 |

```
select temp.project_id from
(select project_id, count(distinct employee_id)
  from Project
  group by project_id
  order by count(distinct employee_id) desc
  )temp
limit 1

select project_id from Project
group by project_id
having count(project_id)=
  (select count(project_id) from Project
   group by Project_id
   order by count(project_id) desc
   limit 1)
```

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag since `limit 1` is not valid SQL Server T-SQL.  MySQL <> SQL Server, make sure to use the tag for only the platform you are actually using.

Comment: One is doing a distinct count of employee_id and the other is counting project_id. Is that a typo?

Comment: I would move the `ORDER BY` clause from the subquery into the main query.

Comment: Why would you think first one wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming employee_ids are unique per project, both would work. Otherwise first would work.

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=94c33e00222d75eb4a7a39d8a0cd4390)

EDIT: This [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=09fb46c4dbf717be94acad2443c4f378) explains why first one would always work while second wouldn't if employee_ids are not unique per project.